Any Chart View in Jetpack Compose
I'm currently working on project that uses AnyChart available at
https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android and I structured my app using jetpack compose.
AnyChart uses a xml view:
<com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

I need some help to integrate the xml view in a composable function.
Can someone help me? Thank you in advance
To use AnyChart I should have a xml view that I set like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>

And to use in a composable function I used AndroidView like this:
@Composable
fun HeatMapChart() {
    // Use AndroidView to embed the AnyChartView
    AndroidView(
        factory ={context ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.heat_map_view, null,false)
            val anyview = view.findViewById<AnyChartView>(R.id.any_chart_view)
            AnyChartView(context).apply {

            }
            view
        },
        update = {view ->


        }

    )

    val riskMap = AnyChart.heatMap()
    
    riskMap.stroke("1 #fff")
    riskMap.title().enabled(false)
    riskMap.labels().enabled(false)

    // Sample data (replace this with your actual data)
    val data: MutableList<DataEntry> = ArrayList()
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Rare", "Insignificant", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Rare", "Minor", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Rare", "Moderate", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Rare", "Major", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Rare", "Extreme", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Unlikely", "Insignificant", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Unlikely", "Minor", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Unlikely", "Moderate", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Unlikely", "Major", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Unlikely", "Extreme", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Possible", "Insignificant", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Possible", "Minor", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Possible", "Moderate", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Possible", "Major", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Possible", "Extreme", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Likely", "Insignificant", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Likely", "Minor", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Likely", "Moderate", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Likely", "Major", 2, "#ef6c00"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Likely", "Extreme", 2, "#ef6c00"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Almost\\nCertain", "Insignificant", 0, "#90caf9"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Almost\\nCertain", "Minor", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Almost\\nCertain", "Moderate", 1, "#ffb74d"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Almost\\nCertain", "Major", 2, "#ef6c00"))
    data.add(CustomHeatDataEntry("Almost\\nCertain", "Extreme", 3, "#d84315"))

    
    // Set the data
    riskMap.data(data)
val context = LocalContext.current
    AndroidView(
        factory ={context ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.heat_map_view, null,false)
            val anyview = view.findViewById<AnyChartView>(R.id.any_chart_view)

            view
        },
        update = {view ->
            AnyChartView(context).apply {
                setChart(riskMap)
            }
        }
    )

}

And I keep getting this error when launching the app : FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: com.example.anycharttest, PID: 11037                                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.anychart.AnyChartView$JsListener com.anychart.AnyChartView.getJsListener()' on a null object reference
